# Why I can't assign a const but i can console log it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I do some java script practice, let several links order by alphabet.

Here is HTML

```
  <a href="#"> a is good </a>
  <a href="#"> c is good </a>
  <a href="#"> b is good </a>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
const allhref= document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (let index in allhref)
  console.log(allhref[index].innerHTML);
```

```html
<a href="#"> a is good </a>
<a href="#"> c is good </a>
<a href="#"> b is good </a>
```

It looks allright, but when i try to assign txt to a const,something wrong(Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token const). here is code.

```js
const allhref= document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (let index in allhref)
  alltext = allhref[index].innerHTML;
console.log(alltext);
```

```html
<a href="#"> a is good </a>
<a href="#"> c is good </a>
<a href="#"> b is good </a>
```

---

Thanks for the replies.
That's a bit strange, i did test it on my computer it has error.
Try different online editor, no error.
here is the code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#">a is good </a>
    <a href="#">c is good </a>
    <a href="#">b is good </a>
  <script type="text/javascript">        
    const allhref= document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (let index in allhref)
      const alltxt = allhref[index].innerHTML;
    console.log(alltxt);
    // console.log(allhref[index].innerHTML);
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: use `let` or `var` instead of `const` to able to change it after first assign

Comment: Why do you use `const` if you want to change the value?

Comment: If you're getting a *SyntaxError*, it doesn't have anything to do with the assignment. The code you provided doesn't show any error.

Comment: As you can see in the snippets there aren't any errors. I guess you forgot a `const alltext;` before the loop. Your problem can't be reproduced. Please provide a [mcve] presenting your error message.

Comment: As I said in you first snippets it was `alltext = allhref[index].innerHTML;`. In the last snippet it is `const alltext = allhref[index].innerHTML;`. That's a huge difference. You can't use `const` for a variable that that you want assign new values.

Comment: Thanks all, I did  try **let** and **var**, same result."not undefined". I think should return the text in <a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

const are immutable in JavaScript. You cannot assign a new value to a const. To be able to do that, change the const to a let.

Comment: Thanks.i try let and var, same result."not undefined".

Answer (score 2):

The definition of const is constant. You can’t change it after initially assigning. Use `let` instead.

Answer (score -2):

Because you you did not use curly-braces ({}) after for-loop and *alltext* parameter is scoped in for loop. If there are more than 1 line after, loops or condition you should use curly-braces. Below code is working.

```
  const allhref= document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (let index in allhref) {
      alltext = allhref[index].innerHTML;
      console.log(alltext);
  }
```

Comment: Why should this cause the error message _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token const_?